# How can I change the value of AuthorizationStatus from a ABAddressBook to kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im needing to access my contact list but since my ABAddressBook keep returning 0 from ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus, I wont be able to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` to request access. This will prompt the user to allow access, and will call your completion block in either case with the result.

Comment: After that. How can I show a list of all contacts from my phone and then select one of them?

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question. Use `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`.

Comment: Thanks I will check for that.